# Setting a Variable in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables

```
$('#firstname').bind('focusout focusin', function() {
    var get_firstname = $("#firstname").val().replace(/ /g, "+");
    var n_firstname = get_firstname.length;
    if (n_firstname > 2) {
        $(".firstname_good").fadeIn("fast");
        var firstname_v = 1;
    }
    else {
        $(".firstname_good").fadeOut("fast");
        var firstname_v = '';
    }
});​
```

I'm have trouble understanding how to use the VAR firstname_v below. What do I need to do in the above to be able to use it below

```
$('#lastname').bind('focusout focusin', function() {
    if (firstname_v == 1) {
        alert(firstname_v);
    }
});​
```

Comment: You need to make it global or put it outside of functions

Comment: Research variable scope. Not understanding variable scope can lead to serious code problems later.

Comment: I don't have a strong understanding of variable scope or Jquery for that matter. That's why I came here with my question. I wanted to hear what the pro's had to say :)

Comment: I would post a link to a tutorial, but there are way too many to choose from.

Comment: Thanks anyway Kevin. I read through several already today. I've been writing php for years but I'm still a newbie when it comes to javascript and jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the variable in a higher scope that both inner scopes have access to:

```
var firstname_v; // declare it

$('#firstname').bind('focusout focusin', function() {
    var get_firstname = $("#firstname").val().replace(/ /g, "+");
    var n_firstname = get_firstname.length;
    if (n_firstname > 2) {
        $(".firstname_good").fadeIn("fast");
        firstname_v = 1; // no var here, you're just setting it
    }
    else {
        $(".firstname_good").fadeOut("fast");
        firstname_v = ''; // no var here, you're just setting it
    }
});​

$('#lastname').bind('focusout focusin', function() {
    if (firstname_v == 1) { // no var here, you're just getting it
        alert(firstname_v);
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your variable is local to the callback function.

Declare it outside like this:

```
   var firstname_v = '';

   $('#firstname').bind('focusout focusin', function() {
    var get_firstname = $("#firstname").val().replace(/ /g, "+");
    var n_firstname = get_firstname.length;
    if (n_firstname > 2) {
        $(".firstname_good").fadeIn("fast");
        firstname_v = 1;
    }
    else {
        $(".firstname_good").fadeOut("fast");
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the top block to:

```
var firstname_v;
$('#firstname').bind('focusout focusin', function() {
    var get_firstname = $("#firstname").val().replace(/ /g, "+");
    var n_firstname = get_firstname.length;
    if (n_firstname > 2) {
        $(".firstname_good").fadeIn("fast");
        firstname_v = 1;
    }
    else {
        $(".firstname_good").fadeOut("fast");
        firstname_v = '';
    }
});​
```

Note that the only real change is that the declaration of `firstname_v` is now done outside the function rather than inside. This was it will be available throughout your code.

Comment: `varfirstname_v;` should be `var firstname_v;`

Comment: @GabrielSantos - Yup, typo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var firstname_v = 0;

$('#firstname').bind('focusout focusin', function() {
    var get_firstname = $("#firstname").val().replace(/ /g,"+");
    var n_firstname = get_firstname.length;

    if (n_firstname > 2) {  
        $(".firstname_good").fadeIn("fast"); 
        firstname_v = 1; 
    } else { 
        $(".firstname_good").fadeOut("fast"); 
    }
});

$('#lastname').bind('focusout focusin', function() {
    if (firstname_v == 1) {
        alert(firstname_v);
    }
});​
```

Comment: i don't think this addresses the issue.

Comment: you dont need to try to see that `firstname_v` would be undefined in the other event handler you didn't post.

Comment: You are right. I have copied only the top of code. Forgot the second `bind`